# OS X how to disable Command P Shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard

I would like to disable Command P shortcuts or change it to something i would not accidentally hit

But i do not see options in Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts

Regards

Comment: Have a look at: [How to disable keyboard shortcuts in mac os x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719135/how-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts such as the "Print Document" shortcut are baked into each application, so unfortunately it isn't something that is system-wide and can be disabled in one place.

Here's an excerpt from Apple's [Keyboard Shortcut page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236):

> To learn more shortcuts, check the menus of the app you're using.
>   Every app can have its own shortcuts, and shortcuts that work in one
>   app may not work in another.

However there is still a workaround to get shortcuts from working, and that would be by using another application that binds shortcuts. By binding Command+P to do nothing on another application you would essentially block it from being able to do anything else. To learn more on how to do this, check out this very similar question: [How to disable keyboard shortcuts in mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719135/how-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-mac-os-x)